# Laragon auto Vartual host file gets reset on refresh

Tags: laravel, server, laragon

hi I have many sites that I want to test on local, so when I edit the files on auto virtual host files under Apache->sites-enabled->file name, after reloading laragon, the file resets to its original default contents, ex-

```
Original
<VirtualHost *:80> 
DocumentRoot "C:/laragon/www/cast.see.tech/public"
ServerName cast.see.tech.test
ServerAlias *.cast.see.tech.test
<Directory "C:/laragon/www/cast.see.tech/public">
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

```
edited
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.101:80> 
DocumentRoot "C:/laragon/www/cast.see.tech/public"
ServerName cast.see.tech.test
ServerAlias *.cast.see.tech.test
<Directory "C:/laragon/www/cast.see.tech/public">
    AllowOverride All
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I cannot save any rules, any code, it comes back to its default original content once I restart laragon server. I am using windows 11, but the same problem I face on windows 10 also.
I tried uninstalling and installing back, but still no luck. Currently i am using latest version of laragon 5.0.0 210523, I also tried downgrading the version but still the same problem. Is it a windows issue or do I need to do something else. Please help me with this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Each project has each own Virtual Host file located in:

*For Apache:*
**{LARAGON_ROOT}\etc\apache2\sites-enabled\auto.{project}.test.conf**

*For Nginx:*
**{LARAGON_ROOT}\etc\nginx\sites-enabled\auto.{project}.test.conf**

Content of a `.conf` file is auto generated. If you have a specific project which has modified content, just remove the `auto.` prefix from config file names eg : `auto.example.test.conf` => `example.test.conf` , Laragon will keep the content of the `.conf` file intact.

Virtual Host content is configurable, you can change it by modifying the template in:

**{LARAGON_ROOT}\usr\tpl\VirtualHost.tpl**

https://laragon.org/docs/pretty-urls.html

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the reply, I will try this.

Answer (score 0):

Laragon uses a template to auto-generate the virtual hosts.

On windows, the file is located at `C:\laragon\usr\tpl\VirtualHost.tpl`, assuming you installed it in `C:\laragon`.

Just edit this file and make the changes you want.

Keep in mind that **all your sites** will now use the same configurations.

One change I personally make is to remove the `*.` from `ServerAlias`, as I use subdomain format for my sites. Before I remove it, subdomain.example.com would always redirect to example.com.

Comment: hi thanks for the reply, for sure I will try this and let you know.

Comment: hi @ruturajvaidya. i hope your issue is resolved by now. i just wanted to mention that you should probably change VirtualHostManifest.tpl instead